# An equation with two splits / differing alignments

Tags: equations, align, split

I would like to layout an equation in the following form:

```
x=5+3-4
     -4+3+5
 =8-8+8
 =8
```

In words: I want to split the equation at two points; one where the first equation splits over two splits and the minus signs align, and the other where the equal signs align.

I've tried using `\equation{}` and `\split{}`, either with two separate ones or trying to nest them, but nothing appears to work! Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can use an `\alignCenterstack` here because the column alignment is `rlrl`.  If it were other, I could always use a `\tabularCenterstack`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\TABbinary
\setstackaligngap{0pt}
\alignCenterstack{
 x=& 5 + 3 &-& 4\\
   &       &-& 4 + 3 + 5\\
   & 8 - 8 &+& 8\\
  =& 8     & &
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

By default in `tabstackengine`, one can think of `&` tabs as being "replaced" with `{}&`, so that all cells have an empty group on the right.  This helps spacing if relations and binary relations are placed at the right side of a cell and unary relations are placed at the left.  In this case, however, I need the `+` and `-` to behave as binary in column 3, so `\TABbinary` instead "replaces" the `&` with `{}&{}`, so that all cell boundaries are padded with an empty group.

The `\setstackaligngap{}` sets the horizontal gap introduced after left-aligned columns of the align-stack, which here I want as `0pt`.

The tabular stack equivalent is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\TABbinary
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\tabularCenterstack{rll}{
 x=& 5 + 3 &- 4\\
   &       &- 4 + 3 + 5\\
   & 8 - 8 &+ 8\\
  =& 8     & 
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use standard `amsmath` tools:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x&=\begin{aligned}[t]
   5+3&-4 \\
      &-4+3+5
   \end{aligned} \\
 &=8-8+8 \\
 &=8
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]